# SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4321

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize ORM with PostgreSQL dialect hosted in a docker container running at localhost. The app is running through port 3050 and the database through port 5432 redirected to 4321.

**The error:**

```
Server is running on port: 3050
Unable to connect to the database: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4321
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: yarn start
    ports:
      - "3050:3050"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app/medtech
      - /home/app/medtech/node_modules
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "4321:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: medtech_dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: uaz0ZWrsCeUG3271GsRB
```

**My db connection snippet**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import Constants from '../utils/constants';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  Constants.database.name,
  Constants.database.user,
  Constants.database.password, {
    host: Constants.database.host,
    port: Constants.database.port,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 10000,
      idle: 20000,
    },
    timezone: Constants.timezone,
  },
);
```

**The constants values are from my .env:**

```
DATABASE_PORT=4321
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_NAME=medtech_dev
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=uaz0ZWrsCeUG3271GsRB
```

**For some reason that I don't know** I'm using a separated file to run my seeds and migrations using exactly the same database constants and **it works**. Here is:

```
const Constants = require('../utils/constants').default;

module.exports = {
  username: Constants.database.user,
  port: Constants.database.port,
  password: Constants.database.password,
  database: Constants.database.name,
  host: Constants.database.host,
  dialect: 'postgres',
};
```

After many changes that I've made through my files and many threads I read I can't think on what is causing that problem. That's my first time using Docker and I don't know if there's something really wrong with my Docker config files or somekind of other mistake.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the constants values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your app container and postgres are running in two different containers that's mean that they are two different machines each machine has it's own ip.

you can't call postgres service from your app container by using `localhost:postgresport` and vice verse , from postgres to app container

it seems that the `Constants.database.host` is localhost or 172.0.0.1 , to reach postgres container you have to call container ip or name or service name

in your case change `Constants.database.host` value to be `postgres` and give it a try

Comment: The constants values came from a .env file which values are the same that we have at docker-compose.yml.

I've changed the host to **'postgres'** and got the same error with a different IP: 172.19.0.2:4321

Comment: `4321` is the exposed port out side docker , if you are going to call it from other container in the same network you have to change port to the local port `5432`

so change port number to be `5432`

Comment: It perfectly worked. Thank you so much! And now I figured it out the reason why my migrations and seeds are working with localhost:4321 it's just because I was running then outside the docker.